# Best way to vanish a ProgressBar once a thread ends

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an indeterminate ProgressBar spinning while a thread is doing some OCR computation, and I want the bar to be set to View.GONE once the thread concludes. However, I'm not sure the best way to register when the thread ends for this purpose. Obviously, I can't just set it to View.GONE inside the thread at the end, or else I'm touching views improperly.

Not really sure if any code is required, since the question is very general, but am happy to provide if requested

Comment: I would like to see some code, normally you would use AsyncTask, which has onPrexcecute and onPostexecute, both running in UI thread to setup and remove progressbar.

Comment: What do you mean by _best way_? What are the options you look into?

Comment: ozbek - Best in most simple and efficient. I know there are several ways this could be implemented, so I wanted to hear people's opinions as to my choices.

Comment: cYrixmorten - I'm going to look into Asynctask as a potentially better/more logical way to implement this. However, Egor's solution below worked like a charm, so I'm going to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's not possible to update Views from outside the UI thread, you should use the `post()` method:

```
progressBar.post(new Runnable() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm going to look into other ways (in my reading, I've seen a good number of ways to do this sort of thing listed) but I wanted something really native and simple, and this seems like that.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's the code that worked for me:

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}});
```